# What would be a good gigabit router for a home with a Windows Home Server?

Tags: router, gigabit-ethernet

I've just got my windows home server and I want to move my DVD copies to it (VOB files), but I'm not sure it will play across my current 10/100.  In fact, the time it takes to transfer the VOB files has discouraged me from completing a test.

I'm not interested in converting all my video to any other format because this device is supposed to save me time, not waste it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ordered an Acer H340 Windows Home Server and chose the [D-Link DIR-655](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833127215) router to go with it. I've currently got a D-Link DGL-4300 router that has been very stable after some initial problems. I'm replacing it primarily because my new laptop supports 802.11n.

Also look at the [TRENDnet TEW-633GR](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833156226) if you want to save a few bucks.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the Linksys Gigabit routers. I never have any problems with Linksys stuff. The DLink stuff should be good too, but I'm not a fan of their interface.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using [this router](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/CA/en/products/WRT310N) and it's been very solid.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [D-Link 4300 Wireless G Router](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833127158) with gig switch.  It has been very solid for over 3 years now.  I would look into the next gen, the [D-Link 4500 Wireless N Router](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833127243) with gig switch.  It rocks!