# How to share internet over network

Tags: networking, setup, proxy-server

I have a machine connected to internet. I want to set up a proxy server or any other configuration that can help me to share internet over other machines in the same network machine may be of diff. platform (linux,mac, , windows), and server can be (either linux or windows)

so how to configure now..
all machine are in network.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set up a [cheap box from ebay](http://item.ebay.com/130384807456) with an extra NIC in it as a router using linux (there are many choices, google it please), connect one of the NIC's to a switch and your other computers to the switch. If you run a DHCP server (dhcpd) on the Linux box, you do not need to configure the other computers at all to get internet. As for the proxy, I have heard much about [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), though I have not tried it myself. It should be easy to get working, post a comment if you want remote installation help.

Answer (score 6):

Purchase a cheap home router and connect each of your devices to the router.  See these questions for recommendations:

- [Good reliable cheap router for dorm room?](https://superuser.com/questions/94095/good-reliable-cheap-router-for-dorm-room)
- [What would be a good gigabit router for a home with a Windows Home Server?](https://superuser.com/questions/11163/what-would-be-a-good-gigabit-router-for-a-home-with-a-windows-home-server)
- [What’s a good, affortable router that will not give me problems when downloading torrents?](https://superuser.com/questions/124153/whats-a-good-affortable-router-that-will-not-give-me-problems-when-downloading)

Comment: can't it be done without router, using some sort of servers ?

Comment: @abc - If all your machines were Windows then possibly, but with different operating systems a router is the way to go.

Comment: @abc, it could be done with what you have currently, but you would essentially have to setup one of your computers to be a router.  Its much simpler and easier to setup/maintain to just get a cheap router and let it do what it does best.

Answer (score 0):

Have your Internet-connected host act as a router by enabling packet forwarding.